# Replicas en kubernetes entre nodos

Tags: asp.net-core, azure, kubernetes

Actualmente estoy desplegando desde mi maquina local en kubernetes con los siguientes comandos

```
docker push  xxxdev.azurecr.io/xxxxoapi:latest 
kubectl run xxxxapi --image=xxxxdev.azurecr.io/travelexpensesparametroapi:latest --replicas=2 --labels app=apixxx

kubectl expose  deployments xxxxxoapi  --port=80 --name=servicio-xxxx --type=NodePort
```

Los anteriores comandos solo hacen replica en el mismo modo, ¿como puedo replicar entre distintos nodos con el fin de que si un nodo llegara a morir los pods dentro de los demás deployments sigan respondiendo?

Answer (score 1):

tienes que agregar antiafinidad entre tus pod's  ejemplo :

```
 affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            -
              labelSelector:
                matchExpressions:
                  -
                    key: app
                    operator: In
                    values:
                      - apixxx
              topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
```